# C# COM Client reads faulty values from Delphi COM Server

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have created a minimal ActiveX Library project with Delphi 10.3 in 32-bit mode.
The COM server exposes a class `Test` which has 3 methods: `EchoInt`, `EchoDouble` and `EchoString`.
Each method writes the input value of the given type to the console and finally returns the unmodified input value.

Now I have created a minimal C# COM client with .NET 6.0 in 32-bit mode.
The client calls each method of the COM server and writes the return values to the console.

The console output of the C# client:

```
[int] Delphi receives: 1234
[int] C# receives: 1234
[double] Delphi receives:  1.23400000000000E+0000
[double] C# receives: NaN
[string] Delphi receives: hello
```

The values which Delphi receives are correct for all 3 value types.
However, the return value is only correct for type `int`.
For `double` it returns `NAN` instead of `1.234`.
For `string` the return value marshalling seems to fail completely as the C# application immediately exits with return code `!= 0` without an exception.

I have tried 64-bit interop as well, which fails with different values.
I have also tried an out-of-process COM Server, which also yields the same faulty values.

How to reproduce? (ready-to-clone: https://github.com/timmi-on-rails/com-server)

### Delphi COM Server

Create a Delphi ActiveX Library Project with the following relevant files.

**ComServer.ridl**

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING
// -------
// This file is generated by the Type Library importer or Type Libary Editor.
// Barring syntax errors, the Editor will parse modifications made to the file.
// However, when applying changes via the Editor this file will be regenerated
// and comments or formatting changes will be lost.
// ************************************************************************ //
// File generated on 30.01.2023 10:26:54 (- $Rev: 12980 $, 8627968).

[
  uuid(92C99953-EA24-487D-A728-956B1338C264),
  version(1.0)

]
library ComServer
{

  importlib("stdole2.tlb");

  interface ITest;
  coclass Test;


  [
    uuid(C293FB27-B8BF-451C-90DE-7CE3C138B0E7),
    helpstring("Interface for Test Object"),
    oleautomation
  ]
  interface ITest: IUnknown
  {
    [id(0x00000065)]
    long _stdcall EchoInt([in] long i);
    [id(0x00000066)]
    double _stdcall EchoDouble([in] double d);
    [id(0x00000067)]
    LPWSTR _stdcall EchoString([in] LPWSTR s);
  };

  [
    uuid(B44B1D0D-6824-41E3-A185-A97AB53C59BA),
    helpstring("Test")
  ]
  coclass Test
  {
    [default] interface ITest;
  };

};
```

**Test.pas**:

```delphi
unit Test;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, ComObj, ComServer_TLB, StdVcl;

type
  TTest = class(TTypedComObject, ITest)
  protected
    function EchoDouble(d: Double): Double; stdcall;
    function EchoInt(i: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    function EchoString(s: PWideChar): PWideChar; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;

function TTest.EchoDouble(d: Double): Double;
begin
  writeln('[double] Delphi receives: ', d);
  Result := d;
end;

function TTest.EchoInt(i: Integer): Integer;
begin
  writeln('[int] Delphi receives: ', i);
  Result := i;
end;

function TTest.EchoString(s: PWideChar): PWideChar;
begin
  writeln('[string] Delphi receives: ', s);
  Result := s;
end;

initialization
  TTypedComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TTest, Class_Test,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

### Register COM Server

Open a command line with elevated rights and execute `regsvr32 ComServer.dll` to register the ActiveX COM library.

### C# COM Client

Create a .NET 6 C# console project with the following relevant files.

**ComClient.csproj**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="ComServer">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>92c99953-ea24-487d-a728-956b1338c264</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Program.cs**:

```csharp
using System;
using ComServer;

var test = new Test();

Console.WriteLine("[int] C# receives: " + test.EchoInt(1234));
Console.WriteLine("[double] C# receives: " + test.EchoDouble(1.234));
Console.WriteLine("[string] C# receives: " + test.EchoString("hello"));
Console.WriteLine("done");
```

Since COM is a mature and established technology, I wonder, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you remove oleautomation from interface definition, see if it changes anything

Comment: @SimonMourier: Exception on `new Test()`: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ComServer.Test'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{C293FB27-B8BF-451C-90DE-7CE3C138B0E7}' failed due to the following error: Unbekannter Fehler (0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).'

Comment: Have you also tried using safecall instead of stdcall?

Comment: @Tom - strange. I don't know delphi so I can't say why this happens, but the interface is clearly not oleautomation (it isn't an IDispatch interface)

Comment: try to add `dual` in idl  ... since you are using `id` attribute it seems like `IDispatch`  on the other side you are deriving from `IUnknown` ... try to use ILSpy and paste code generated by tlbimp in C# ... also returning `LPWSTR` is asking for trouble... (you should rather fill the buffer passed by caller

Comment: or maybe remove id attribute

Comment: @Selvin: Adding dual had no effect. About string buffers. I thought COM marshalling solves these low-level issues for me?!
I created the idl with the Delphi COM Object expert and default values.

Comment: @USauter: Thanks for the safecall hint! It guided me in the right direction.
I tested a C# COM Server and Delphi COM Client, which worked perfectly.
So I inspected the type library and found the expected function signatures, which I mirrored to the Delphi COM Server.
I will post the answer soon.

Comment: You are returning plain pointer to wide chars... Someone has to take responsibility to alloc and free it... Either you will have memory leaks if you alloc and not free or undefined behaviour if you return not longer valid allocated memory(fx stack allocated variable)

Comment: @Selvin: LPWSTR was actually the wrong type, I thought it's the recommended string type. I use BSTR now. Your argumentation would apply to BSTR as well?! If so, then my allocation spamming program can not confirm any leak.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/allocating-and-releasing-memory-for-a-bstr ... *When you call into a function that expects a BSTR argument, you must allocate the memory for the BSTR before the call and release it afterwards.* and *When you call into a function that returns a BSTR, you must free the string yourself.* - **you don't care about this because C# marshaler will do this...** *When you implement a function that returns a BSTR, allocate the string but do not free it. The receiving function releases the memory* this apply to you and you should return BTR* allocated

Comment: If you provide the flesh of the COM object in a Delphi dll, then you have to wait until the C# garbage collector has resolved its references to the object before unloading the dll.